# Validation messages not removed after resetting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I have a html form and I am using angular JS for validation. Here, after submitting the form I am calling the reset method which will reset the form input fields to default.

But, when I submit and call reset method, the validation messages appears in the input field. I have used the below code. I don't want to see the validation messages after submitting the form.

**HTML**

```
<form name="createvalidation" role="form" class="col-lg-12" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Challenge name" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" ng-model="challenge.challengename" required>
        <span ng-show="(createvalidation.name.$dirty || submitted) && createvalidation.name.$error.required">Name is reqiured</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="2" placeholder="Write more about this challenge..." name="description" ng-model="challenge.challengedescription" required></textarea>
        <span ng-show="(createvalidation.description.$dirty || submitted) && challengecreatevalidation.description.$error.required">Description is reqiured</span>
    </div>
</form>
<div>

    <button type="button" ng-click="createChallenge()">Create</button>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
 $scope.createChallenge = function() {
     //get the field and store in db
     $scope.resetForm();
 }
 $scope.master = {};
 $scope.resetForm = function() {

     $scope.challenge = angular.copy($scope.master);
     $scope.createvalidation.$setPristine();
 }
```

Comment: here is http://plnkr.co/edit/UNCmtgEQbt3P11Q8Nfjp?p=preview plunkr, not able to reproduce issue

Comment: could you please try to reproduce the issue\ with given plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.createChallenge = function() {
  //get the field and store in db
 $scope.resetForm();
 }

 $scope.master = {};
 $scope.resetForm = function() {
 $scope.submitted = false; //Try adding this
 $scope.challenge = angular.copy($scope.master);
 $scope.createvalidation.$setPristine();
```

}

Comment: <span ng-show="(createvalidation.description.$dirty || submitted) && createvalidation.description.$error.required">Description is reqiured</span>

Comment: There is an error in that line. You need to change  to createvalidation.description.$error.required

Comment: Happy to help. Was  createvalidation.description.$error.required the issue?

Comment: No i already had the line in my code but while copying here i left that by mistake. $scope.submitted = false, solved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be copying the pristine state of the form from **within** the resetForm function. This means that it will only have the version of the form when resetForm is called. Instead perhaps you should be doing that copy whenever the form is setup and pristine.

Comment: can you help me with a code , I am not able to get you

Comment: Either I misread your code due to the formatting or you updated it after I looked at it. I created a plunker and it seems to be fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/qiRcgcsbpbl210ze49aA?p=preview