# Angularjs : Hide error message after reset the form, coming on second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am using Angularjs and ionic for developing Hybrid Mobile app

HTML :

```
<form name="Form" novalidate > 
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="data.firstName" name="uFirstName" required="" autocomplete="off"/>
    </label>
    <br>
    <div ng-show="Form.$submitted || Form.uFirstName.$touched">
        <span class="error" ng-show="Form.uFirstName.$error.required">Tell us your First Name.</span>
        <span class="error" ng-show="Form.uFirstName.$error.text">This is not a valid First Name.</span>
    </div>  
    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="Form.$valid && callfunction(data,Form)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS :

```
var defaultForm = {firstName: ""};

$scope.data1 = angular.copy(defaultForm);
$scope.callfunction = function(data,Form) { 
    $scope.Form = Form; 
        service.sendData(contact)
            .success(function(data,status,headers){ 
                if(data === true){  
                    $state.go('app.search', {}, {reload: true});
                    $scope.Form.$setPristine();
                    $scope.data1 = angular.copy(defaultForm); 
                }else{ 
                    $ionicPopup.alert({title: 'ERROR',template: 'Data can not be sent'});   
                }
            })
            .error(function(){ 
                $ionicPopup.alert({title: 'ERROR',template: 'Server is not reachable'});   
            }) 
}
```

I have written my code for form validation same as above code.
So what i need to do, click on submit button after get success data from server i have to reset the Form.
Once after success data from server i have to navigating from this page to other page, Again if i am coming to the same page, "Tell us your First Name" error message is showing on that screen.
How do I handle this situation so that after reset the form I will move onto that page without any error message like initial Form.
I tried `"$scope.submitted = false; "` from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599600/validation-messages-not-removed-after-resetting-the-form) but not working.

Comment: How to reproduce it ?

Comment: I think you must use ng-pristine

Comment: not able to reproduce any online editor.I tried but on page change, form is reseting without any business logic in online editor.